# Invalid Operation Exception: Cannot provide a value for property

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-8

Im trying to create a Login page for my blazor web assembly project. I keep getting this error Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)

Here's the page that is getting this error

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject IAuthenticationService AuthService
@inject NavigationManager NavManger
@using WebApp.Client.Authentication


<img src="./images/logo.png"/>

@if(showAuthenticationError)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        @authenticationErrorMessage
    </div>
}

<EditForm Model="model" OnInvalidSubmit="ExecuteLogin" class="card card-body bg-light mt-5">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <ValidationSummary/>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputText id="email" class="form-conrol" @bind-Value="model.Email" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Email)"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <InputText type="password" id="password" class="form-conrol" @bind-Value="model.Password" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Password)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn amr-btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private AuthenticationUserModel model = new();
    private bool showAuthenticationError = false;
    private string authenticationErrorMessage = "";

    private async Task ExecuteLogin()
    {
        showAuthenticationError = false;

        var result = AuthService.Login(model);

        if(result is not null)
        {
            NavManger.NavigateTo("/home");
        }
        else
        {
            authenticationErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password";
            showAuthenticationError = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my program page

```
using Blazored.LocalStorage;using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;using WebApp.Client.Authentication;
```

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
```

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, AuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

```
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Heres my AuthenticationService Page:

```
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using WebApp.Client.Models;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace WebApp.Client.Authentication
{
    public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
        public AuthenticationService(HttpClient client, AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
        {
            _client = client;
            _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticatedUserModel> Login(AuthenticationUserModel userForAuthentication)
        {
            var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userForAuthentication.UserName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", userForAuthentication.Password)
            });

            var authResult = await _client.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/token", data);
            var authContent = await authResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (authResult.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Deserialize the JSON object
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthenticatedUserModel>(authContent, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", result.AccessToken);

            ((AuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserAuthentication(result.AccessToken);

            // Set the token in the HTTP client
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);

            return result;
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("authToken");
            ((AuthStateProvider)_authStateProvider).NotifyUserLogout();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable<int> parentComponentId)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, int frameIndex, int parentComponentId)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(ref DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(ref DiffContext diffContext, int newFrameIndex)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(ref DiffContext diffContext, int oldStartIndex, int oldEndIndexExcl, int newStartIndex, int newEndIndexExcl)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, int componentId, ArrayRange<RenderTreeFrame> oldTree, ArrayRange<RenderTreeFrame> newTree)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, out Exception renderFragmentException)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent component, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(HttpContext httpContext, Type rootComponentType, ParameterView parameters, bool waitForQuiescence)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c+<<InvokeAsync>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

It might be something really dumb that I'm just missing but for the life of me i cant find it. So if someone could help me out that would be really nice.

Comment: Please add the error details with stacktrace